# In Yosuga no Sora, why is Akira Amatsume portrayed as having a big head in gag shorts?

Tags: yosuga-no-sora

Amatsume Akira (the shrine maiden girl) in Yosuga no Sora seems to always have a gag where she's portrayed with a huge head. This happens during the ending gag shorts (first pic), as well as the ED song (second pic). This literally only happens with her, and consistently. Is there some joke/pun I'm missing for why this is done? In the actual anime itself, she seems to look totally normal, without a big head or forehead or anything.

[image: amatsume akira gag]

[image: amatsume akira ed]